# High ping on games while streaming

Tags: streaming

I'm streaming with Elgato Capture Card to Twitch. I get high pings on games while streaming (1700kbps). How can I decrease pings while streaming? Here is my bandwidth:

[image: Results]

Comment: Looks like a question for [su].

Comment: Um, 1700kbps is your streaming bandwidth, not your ping.  Decreasing that number will decrease the quality of your stream.  Your ping, according to your speed test, is 31 milliseconds, which is actually pretty good.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm sure the speedtest will have been taken without the stream or game running, so I'd guess the ping latency in the image is not relevant in that context. I think that's provided just to show the available bandwidth.

Comment: @Bryan I realize that, but without actual numbers, it's hard to make a suggestion that isn't more than a guess.  Also, it not entirely clear that the asker knows the proper terminology.

Comment: @MBraedley Actual ping speeds whilst the game and stream are running are pretty much irrelevant, all we need to know is that they're high (which he says they are). Clearly when this occurs, quality of stream and game will suffer. The OP does specify that the speedtest is to show available bandwidth. I can see why you might think his terminology was wrong, but I didn't read as you did, as I read `(1700kbps)` as being in context of the stream, not the ping.

Comment: @MBraedley I know 1700kbps is my bandwidth. The results were taken without streaming to show my actual bandwidth.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general network bandwidth issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost completely saturating your upload bandwidth with the stream you're sending. Despite streaming out not using much of your download speed, you need plenty of bandwidth available in both directions to have reduced latency in games.

As I see it, you've two options.

1. Increase the available bandwidth on your upload speed. You can achieve this by either reducing the quality of your stream, or increasing the available upload speed.
2. Purchase a router with Quality of Service (QoS), this will allow you to prioritise traffic. You need to set a lower priority on stream traffic, so the game latency is reduced.

Ideally, I'd suggest you considered implementing both options, if you want the best performance for both the stream and the game.

For what it's worth, I do think trying to stream at 1700kbps is way too high for an upload speed of 1.92Mbps. For best performance, I'd be reducing that to around half of your available upload bandwidth, i.e. 1000kbps.

Comment: I tried 1000kbps on 480p. getting 100 ping on csgo.

Comment: You're always going to get increased ping latency when other traffic is using your connection, unless you use QoS on your router. Reducing the stream bandwidth will help, but QoS is better (and both is better still).

Comment: Then, can you help me configuring QoS on my router? It's complicated. http://s11.postimg.org/hhbu7fjr7/Ads_z.png here is my QoS tab.

Comment: @WalkerJetBat. Like I said before: looks like a question for [su].

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. (I though Super User was an user. LOL)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you upload speed =(. When you are streaming, you are **sending** a lot of data, so your ping will get highter. You may call to your internet service provider (ISP) to ask if they can raise your upload speed.

Also try to decrease the quality of your stream. By quality I mean, for example, from 720p to 480p.

Comment: ISP says "We cannot increase your upload speed."